# Coproduct of Group Homomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, morphism

I've been trying to work through the following problem:

> Let $H$, $G$, and $G'$ be groups, and let $f:H\to G$ and $g:H\to G'$ be two homomorphisms. Define the notion of coproduct of these two homomorphisms over $H$, and show that it exists.

I'm new to category theory and free groups, so I'm pretty lost on this. Here's what I *do* know:

**Definition.** If $\{A_{j}\}_{j\in J}$ is a family of objects in a category $\mathscr{A}$, then their coproduct is a pair $(S,\{f_{j}\}_{j\in J})$ consisting of an object $S$ and a family of morphisms $\{f_{j}:A_{j}\to S\}$ such that, given a family of morphisms $\{g_{j}:A_{j}\to T\}$, there exists a unique morphism $h:S\to T$ such that $h\circ f_{j}=g_{j}$ for all $j\in J$.

I'm really confused as to how to apply this definition. I'm assuming that I need to take my category to be the category of all groups, but I'm not sure. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Usually it's hard to guess what the (co)product is.

Comment: The "coproduct of two homomorphisms" here is what is sometimes called the "pushout". You are looking for a group $K$, and homomorphisms $u\colon G\to K$, $u'\colon G'\to K$ such that $uf=u'g$, and such that for all groups $M$ and homomorphisms $t\colon G\to M$ and $t'\colon G'\to M$ such that $tf=t'g$, there exists a unique homomorphism $v\colon K\to M$ such that $t=vu$ and $t'=vu'$.

Comment: It sounds like you are working in the coslice category $H/\mathbf{Grp}$, in which case, as Arturo Magidin states, what you want is the pushout of $f$ and $g$ in $\mathbf{Grp}$.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the free product of $G$ and $G^\prime$ where you identify $f(h)$ with $g(h)$.